# Passing data through iFrame

Tags: javascript, html, wcf

I've made a WCF mini-questionnaire service with the following functions.

```
RegisterUser(string cookieID): void
ThrowQuestion(string cookieID): Question
AnswerQuestion(string cookieID, int QuestionID, int AnswerID): void
```

The goal of the questionnaire is to ask one new question to a user every time he loads a certain web page (probably a web page an employee needs to preform his job).

I give the admin of the page a piece of code in a div-element so he has the choice of the location, look and feel.

I've tried using an iframe-element with a web page of mine which displays the question as source, but I can't seem to pass data through the iFrame to the source page (eg. the cookie)

I there a way to make this work? Maybe an alternative for the iFrame?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Add a form with Radio buttons or Checkboxes in HTML then use some PHP or JavaScript to have it do the other features. Take a look [***here***](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_forms.asp)

Comment: I've rephrased my question